# How to increase the number before slash in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to increase the number before slash in excel when i drag down. for eg 001/2016 when I drag down and fill the series it should be 002/2016 003/2016, 004/2016 and so on instead of 001/2016, 001/2017, 001/2018 and so on.

Comment: Have you tried entering the first two items before dragging?

Answer (score 3):

If you're starting in row 1, you could use a formula like:

```
=TEXT(ROW(),"000")&"/2016"
```

If you're starting in a different row, include a numeric adjustment to the row number.  When you copy or drag that formula down, it will create your values based on the row number.